# Restart EC2 instance on Website unavailability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website hosted on an EC2 server. I want to monitor the website endpoint and restart the EC2 instance if the website in unavailable for a certain time frame (say 60 seconds).
What tools do I use in AWS and how do I accomplish this?

Comment: you want to restart it manually or using script?

Comment: restart without any human intervention

Comment: Are you using Route 53 for DNS and/or ELB for load balancing?

Comment: why do you need to restart the whole server versus looking for the process or service that is responsible for making the website endpoint available?

Comment: No. We are not using Route53 or ELB. We have an elastic IP configured to the server. We are aware that the issue needs to be investigated and the root cause should be fixed. This will take time. We need an immediate solution which is restart the server

Comment: okay. What do you mean by restart? do you want a simple `reboot` command or the `stop ec2 instance and start the ec2 instance functionality like doing it in the aws console`? You might want to create additional aws resources like lambda and cloudwatch alarms to fully automate the restart process without human intervention if the later kind of restart is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that this is not a best practice in AWS but can make some sense - e.g. you are running a small personal web server with low demand where availability is a less issue than costs.

At least that was my reason why I built automation for it.

**diagram**
[image]

**lambda code**

```py
import json
import os
import boto3
import time

env_vars = [
    'ALARM_NAME',
    'REGION',
    'INSTANCE_ID',
    'OUTPUT_SNS_ARN'
    ]

ENV = {}

for env_var in env_vars:
    ENV[env_var] = os.environ.get(env_var, None)
    if not ENV[env_var]:
        raise Exception(f"Environment variable {env_var} must be set!")


def reboot_instance(instanceID, regionName) -> "instanceID":
    """
    InstanceID
    instanceID - ID of instance
    regionName - name of region

    return InstanceID or False in case of exception
    """
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=regionName)
    instance = ec2.Instance(instanceID)

    try:
        instance.stop()
        time.sleep(30)
        instance.stop(Force=True)
    except:
        pass

    for i in range(180): # wait 3 minutes
        instance = ec2.Instance(instanceID)
        if instance.state['Code'] == 80:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        raise Exception('Unable to stop instance')

    instance.start()
    return instanceID


def notify_about_reboot(instanceID, snsarn) -> True:
    """
    Put SNS message about reboot to snsarn
    """
    client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')
    client.publish(TopicArn=snsarn, Message=f'EC2 instance {instanceID} was rebooted!')
    return True


def lambda_handler(event, context) -> "status about reboot":
    """
    event: see events/event.json 
    """
    print('EVENT:')
    print(event)
    for record in event.get('Records', None):
        sns = record.get('Sns', None)
        message = json.loads(sns.get('Message', None))
        msgalarm =  message.get('AlarmName', None)
        msgstatus = message.get('NewStateValue', None)

        if not all([sns,message,msgalarm,msgstatus]):
            continue

        if (msgalarm == ENV['ALARM_NAME']) and (msgstatus == 'ALARM'):
            notify_about_reboot(reboot_instance(ENV['INSTANCE_ID'], ENV['REGION']), ENV['OUTPUT_SNS_ARN'])
            return 'rebooting'
        else:
            return 'nothing to do'

    return 'no sns record found'
```

I have released whole tested automation with SAM template and installation instructions also on https://github.com/koss822/misc/tree/master/Aws/route53-healthcheck-instance-reboot

Answer (score 3):

This is not a recommended approach.

Firstly, if a website is unavailable, you would probably want to **investigate the cause** rather than just restarting the instance. Your goal should be to run a stable system by removing root causes of problems rather than just ignoring the problem by restarting all the time.

The recommended design would be to run in a **Highly Available** configuration with:

- The application running on **at least two servers** across at least two Availability Zones (in case of failure of an AZ). This is not necessarily more expensive because each server can be smaller than a single, large server.
- A **load balancer** in front of the instances, distributing the traffic to the instances. The load balancer also performs continuous health checks and stops sending requests to servers that fail the health check
- An **Auto Scaling group** that can terminate unhealthy instances and automatically launch replacement servers. This also works well if an Availability Zone should fail.

In this design, an unhealthy instance would be *terminated* (stopped and destroyed) and a new instance created with a pre-defined disk image and startup script. Alternatively, you might choose to move bad instances out of the Auto Scaling group for investigation of the problem, with a new instance being launched to take its place.

If your application requires a database, **the database should be external to the instances** so that all instances can connect to the database and replacing application instances does not cause any data loss.

As to the speed of noticing problems on a server, the load balancer can perform checks every few seconds. Amazon CloudWatch, on the other hand, would need at least a minute to detect problems (probably longer since metrics are calculated over a period rather than being "now" metrics).

Comment: We would be implementing a high available configuration in time. However, in the meantime we need to keep the service running on the current configuration. Hence this solution of restarting the server.

Answer (score 2):

John's approach is the correct one, but at its simplest:

- Write a lambda function that can query your website and see if it is running or not and if not have that lambda function restart the instance.
- Setup a cloudwatch event rule that runs on a frequency you determine to call the lambda function

I'll leave to you the work of writing the code that determines if the website is functional and restarting the server - but that is pretty straightforward. You can use python, java, node, go or .net core in your lambda function - I would think python would be the easiest in this case, but that is an opinion.